# windows 10 how to disable "win" key without using the keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard

My windows 10 laptop thinks that the "win" key is stuck. I have tried to clean it but my guess is that it may be a heat problem. I tried booting a Ubuntu OS but this gave the same results.
If I press any key that is part of a Win shortcut it will perform the shortcut. I tried to uninstall the drivers but the keyboard had the same problem.  I would like to run regedit but pressing the "r" or the "e" takes me to the relevant shortcut window. If I do not touch the keyboard then (about a minute later) a random shortcut window appears and it has focus.
If I could somehow delete all copies of the i8042.sys file (using a USB OS) then reboot without wifi connection then there would be no driver and I could possibly use an external USB keyboard.

The on-screen keyboard shows the Win key as being pressed.

I cannot move the SSD drive to another laptop because of the skills required to disassemble it.

Thank you.

Comment: I would take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Same issue in two different operating systems most likely means the keyboard needs to be replaced. Can you do that?

Comment: I don't have equipment e.g. glue gun to do the keyboard replacement job. I suppose that I am looking for a more radical software solution because I cannot type or risk entering regedit without other windows potentially corrupting the register.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably hardware.
It's possible to disable this key,
but this will cause some difficulties with useful
key-combinations that use it.

To disable the <kbd>Win</kbd> key:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to this key:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
- Right-click on an empty spot on the right
  "New | DWORD (32-bit) Value" and name it `NoWinKeys`
- Double-click the `NoWinKeys` item and change its value to `1`
- The change will become effective after restart.

Additional methods may be found in the article
[How to disable the Windows Key in Windows 10 [FULL GUIDE]](https://windowsreport.com/disable-windows-key/).